# Commandline Argument

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length == 0) { //If nothing is typed into the command line, the message below is printed
        System.out.println("(!)You have not entered anything in the commandline.");
    }else if (args.length > 0){
        try {
            Integer x = new Integer(0);
            if (x<=0){
                System.out.println("(!)You may not have a negative number in the command line.");
            }
            x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException y) {
            System.out.println("(!)Your entry in the commandline must be an integer.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I tried entering a postive number into the commandline but it keeps running my println: "(!)You may not have a negative number" even though x(what I typed into the command line) is not <= 0. I have a feeling I forgot to add something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Integer x = new Integer(0);
            if (x<=0){
                System.out.println("(!)You may not have a negative number in the command line.");
            }
            x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

What else you can expect here, you are initializing with zero and checking the if condition immediately.

You have to pars the `arg[0]` to integer first and then have your logic after that

You have to write

```
 Integer  x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            if (x<=0){
                System.out.println("(!)You may not have a negative number in the command line.");
            }
```

Comment: @Xirol Glad to help you.